# Show upstream Cloudflare server IP after enabled nginx / set_real_ip_from

Tags: nginx, networking, cloudflare, x-forwarded-for

I've followed cloudflare doc [1] that enabled `set_real_ip_from` in order to show original client's IP

My log format is

`log_format  main  '$remote_addr $http_cf_connecting_ip $http_x_forwarded_for`

Assume client real IP is X, and cloudflare server is Y

#### Before enabling

the log is `Y X X`

#### After enabling

the log is `X X X`

#### Questions

1. Is this normal?
2. After enabled, the CF server IP info is lost, how to log them?

[1] https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-Logging-visitor-IP-addresses-with-mod-cloudflare-

Answer (score 1):

When you use the realip module to substitute the client IP address for the downstream proxy IP address (in this case Cloudflare), the original proxy IP address that contacted you is stored in the variable `$realip_remote_addr` and the remote port in `$realip_remote_port`. You can use these variables in your custom `log_format`.